# Display Select2 Multi Option Not Showing All Results

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

so I have a Select2 Multi dropdown and would like to simply return all the selected values.

Currently, in my JS file, the selected_options stores the value but seems to ignore every option except the first selected option.

Is it possible to return all the selected values in an array?
e.g.

['Graph1','Graph2','Graph3','Graph4']
Many thanks in advance!

```
    $(".graph-selection").select2().on("change", function(s){

        var selected_options = s.val();
        console.log(selected_options);

    )};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
var selected_options = $(this).val();
```